# Extract digits from string - Google spreadsheet

Tags: regex, google-sheets, extract, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

In Google spreadsheets, I need a formula to extract all digits (0 to 9) contained into an arbitrary string, that might contain any possible character and put them into a single cell.

Examples (Input -> Output)

```
d32Ελληνικάfe9j.r/3-fF66 -> 329366
h01j2j3jFxF$$4j5j6j7j8j9 -> 0123456789
```

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You may replace all non-digit characters using the `\D+` regex and an empty string replacement with

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A11,"\D+", "")
```

or with casting it to a number:

```
=VALUE(REGEXREPLACE(A11,"\D+", ""))
```

[image]

Answer (score 28):

These work with integers, **decimals** and **negatives**:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A2,"-*\d*\.?\d+")
=VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(A2,"-*\d*\.?\d+"))
```

[image: regex negative decimals - google sheets function]

Comment: This is a usefull answer and thansk for posting. However the question is not about extracting numbers but just the digits from 0 to 9.

Comment: I found this question as the top result from my search for how to parse numbers in a Google Sheet.  I know that it's not technically the correct answer to the question but it's the answer that I needed.

Answer (score 5):

If some of source cells may contain only numbers it is safer to convert the value to text first, then regexreplace. Otherwise it produces error.

Result as text

```
=REGEXREPLACE(TO_TEXT(C1),"\D+", "")
```

Result as number

```
=VALUE(REGEXREPLACE(TO_TEXT(C1),"\D+", ""))
```

The same for whole column

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(C1:C), VALUE(REGEXREPLACE(TO_TEXT(C1:C),"\D+", ""))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to extract with decimal points, you could use regexextract:

```
=VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(B4,"[0-9]*\.[0-9]+[0-9]+"))
```

Example to extract digits, a decimal and 2 significant digits:

```
=VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"[0-9]*\.[0-9]+[0-9]+"))
```

Output:

[image: Extract just digits, decimal, and 2 significant digits]

Comment: This code works only for special cases like this and it will not for my examples.

Comment: Thought others might benefit from additional use cases and regextract can be more useful than the above example.

Comment: Might be but solves a different problem such as: "Retrive value from values with unit of measure. I would let admins decide.

Comment: I needed to extract with decimals too, this works in random sentences: =REGEXEXTRACT(H13, "\d+.\d+")

Answer (score 1):

array formula variant:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A1:A<>""; REGEXREPLACE(A1:A; "\D+"; )*1; ))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 1):

```
=VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(B4,"[+-]?[0-9,.]+"))
```

`1,670.87USD` becomes `1670.87`

Answer (score 0):

You could do a find and replace (Edit -> Find and Replace), searching for the regex `[^\d]` (anything not a digit) and replacing with nothing.

[image]

Comment: I forgot to add that this needs to be a formula so it will be able to work as data are coming.